# Selecting appropriate lines of a list using indexing

Tags: python, indexing, line

I want to extract lines in a list that contain carbons ('C').

The actual lines are:

```
propene_data = ['H        -0.08677109049370    0.00000005322169    0.02324774260533\n', 'C        -0.02236345244409   -0.00000001742911    1.09944502076327\n', 'C         1.14150994274008    0.00000000299501    1.72300489107368\n', 'H        -0.95761218150040   -0.00000002374717    1.63257861279343\n', 'H         1.17043966864771    0.00000000845005    2.80466760537188\n', 'C         2.46626448549704   -0.00000000616665    1.02315746104893\n', 'H         3.28540550052797    0.00000001315434    1.73628424885091\n', 'H         2.55984407099540   -0.87855375749407    0.38655722260408\n', 'H         2.55984405602998    0.87855372701591    0.38655719488850\n']
```

I've tried to extract the carbons line using the following solution;

```
car1 = propene_data[1].split()
car2 = propene_data[2].split()
car3 = propene_data[5].split()

propene_carbons = car1 + car2 + car3
```

This solution gives;

```
propene_carbons = ['C', '-0.02236345244409', '-0.00000001742911', '1.09944502076327', 'C', '1.14150994274008', '0.00000000299501', '1.72300489107368', 'C', '2.46626448549704', '-0.00000000616665', '1.02315746104893']
```

It gives what I want, but I would like to know if I could indexing instead (in case the list is much longer). How do I use indexing in this case?

Comment: Do you only want to extract numbers from the strings which begin with `C`?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract strings start from 'C' using indexing if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is `startswith`:

```
result = text.startswith('C')
```

in loop:

```
result = [i for i in propene_data if i.startswith('C')]
```

Output:

> ```
> ['C        -0.02236345244409   -0.00000001742911    1.09944502076327\n', 
> 'C         1.14150994274008    0.00000000299501    1.72300489107368\n', 
> 'C         2.46626448549704   -0.00000000616665    1.02315746104893\n']
> ```

Comment: I don't believe this is correct because it doesn't provide an indexed sum of the numbers, rather just appends them all within a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
propene_array=np.array([i.split() for i in propene_data])
sub_array=np.where(propene_array[:,0]=='C')[0]
propene_carbon=[]
for i in sub_array :
  propene_carbon+=list(propene_array[i])
```

output  :

```
['C', '-0.02236345244409', '-0.00000001742911', '1.09944502076327', 'C', 
 '1.14150994274008', '0.00000000299501', '1.72300489107368', 'C', 
'2.46626448549704', '-0.00000000616665', '1.02315746104893']
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but i don't intend to split all data in the line. i should extract the whole lines that have carbon('C') in it.